# SQLAlchemy: How to get the model or model name of a related model from a foreign key column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to be able to get the model or name of the relevant model from a foreign key column i.e. not the current model which the foreign key is defined but the related model / table. Django has the functionality as it allows programtic and generic functions. I'm surprised this isn't easy to find in SQLAlchemy.